# How to update the attribute options programmatically in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to update/add the options of a drop down attribute in Magento though code (programmatically). I have found how to add attribute options, but how can I update the option values.

Example:
Suppose the attribute is 'manufacturer'. I have added three options man1, man2, man3. Now through my custom code I want to change the label of man1 to man11 and man2 to man22. How can I achieve that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found a solution myself. [See complete details here](http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/05/addupdate-attribute-option-values.html).

```
//Get the eav attribute model
$attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');

//Load the particular attribute by id
//Here 73 is the id of 'manufacturer' attribute
$attr_model->load(73);

//Create an array to store the attribute data
$data = array();

//Create options array
$values = array(
    //15 is the option_id of the option in 'eav_attribute_option_value' table
    15 => array(
            0 => 'Apple'    //0 is current store id, Apple is the new label for the option
        ),
    16 => array(
            0 => 'HTC'
        ),
    17 => array(
            0 => 'Microsoft'
        ),
);

//Add the option values to the data
$data['option']['value'] = $values;

//Add data to our attribute model
$attr_model->addData($data);

//Save the updated model
try {
    $attr_model->save();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
    $session->addSuccess(
        Mage::helper('catalog')->__('The product attribute has been saved.'));

    /**
     * Clear translation cache because attribute labels are stored in translation
     */
    Mage::app()->cleanCache(array(Mage_Core_Model_Translate::CACHE_TAG));
    $session->setAttributeData(false);
    return;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $session->addError($e->getMessage());
    $session->setAttributeData($data);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try extending the AttributeController located at app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\Product\AttributeController.php and override the `saveAction()` method to suit your needs.

Comment: in the saveAction(), all configurations need to be set for the attribute. However, I just want to update the option labels an not any other configuration.