# Magento Attribute Values - add description field

Tags: magento, attributes, entity-attribute-value

Looking for a way to add a description field to invididual attribute *values* in Magento. Please note I'm referring to Attribute Value options, not the actual Attribute itself.

As an example:

Attribute = colour

Attribute values:
Red, Green, Blue

I want to add a description field for each of the 3 colours (1 for Red, 1 for Green, 1 for Blue). The purpose of this is to show a tooltip on the frontend to give more information about each colour option.

Does anyone know how to do this? There are lots of solutions round which apply to the Attribute itself (colour) but not the individual options (Red, Green, Blue).

The descriptions should be editable from within the Admin panel. I don't want a solution which relies on editing these straight in the database using, for example, phpMyAdmin.

I understand that the values are stored in the 'eav_attribute_option_value' table and that a further column may be needed to store the Description. No idea how to get all that set up in the Admin panel. Ideas?

[image: Screenshot of where descriptions need adding]
EDIT: I've added a screenshot of where the Description text would need adding. So next to each colour (on the screenshot: Black, Blue, Green, Grey, Red, White, etc) - each one needs to have a description next to it.

Comment: can you show me a screen shot on where you want this new field ? actually my answer is to add new field in the custom option values.

Comment: In the Admin panel under Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes. Click into an attribute and then go to the tab which is labelled "Manage Labels / Options". So if we have 3 colours listed (red, green, blue) I need a field next to each one of those to add a description next to their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This maybe 11 months out of date, but for anyone else having this problem then perhaps this can assist you. I hope it will save you from the hours of head banging against a wall like myself and my colleague experienced. For my purpose, I was trying to create an **Image URL** field for Magento version 1.9 to support a product migration from an older platform.

This answer has been partially answered here - [Creating new options for Magento attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559681/creating-new-options-for-magento-attributes) but there are some extra things I had to figure out:

1.) This answer assumes you have created your own module (if you do not know how then start here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/)

2.) It also leaves you to create the extra fields in **catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml** yourself. But to save you time here are the amendments I made to to get it to appear in the admin. Create a new table head option on line **88**:

```
<th><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE') ?></th>
```

Next create a new td on line **101**:

```
<td class="a-left"><input class="input-text" type="text" name="option[YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE][{{id}}]" value="{{TABLE_COLUMN_NAME_HERE}}" <?php if ($this->getReadOnly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?>/></td>
```

And also, most of the logic is done in Javascript so we need to replicate the field here on line **126**:

```
    '<td><input class="input-text" type="text" name="option[YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE][{{id}}]" value="{{TABLE_COLUMN_NAME_HERE}}" <?php if ($this->getReadOnly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?>/><\/td>'+
```

3.) The longest part for me was creating the custom logic for **_saveOption** method. I overrode the parent class, but to save you the trouble here is my logic:

```
protected function _saveOption(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $option = $object->getOption();
    if (is_array($option)) {
        $adapter            = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
        $optionTable        = $this->getTable('eav/attribute_option');
        $optionValueTable   = $this->getTable('eav/attribute_option_value');

        $stores = Mage::app()->getStores(true);
        if (isset($option['value'])) {
            $attributeDefaultValue = array();
            if (!is_array($object->getDefault())) {
                $object->setDefault(array());
            }

            foreach ($option['value'] as $optionId => $values) {
                $intOptionId = (int) $optionId;
                if (!empty($option['delete'][$optionId])) {
                    if ($intOptionId) {
                        $adapter->delete($optionTable, array('option_id = ?' => $intOptionId));
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                $sortOrder = !empty($option['order'][$optionId]) ? $option['order'][$optionId] : 0;
                $imgUrl = !empty($option['image_url'][$optionId]) ? $option['image_url'][$optionId] : 0;
                if (!$intOptionId) {
                    $data = array(
                       'attribute_id'  => $object->getId(),
                       'sort_order'    => $sortOrder,
                       'image_url'     => $imgUrl
                    );
                    $adapter->insert($optionTable, $data);
                    $intOptionId = $adapter->lastInsertId($optionTable);
                } else {
                    $data  = array('sort_order' => $sortOrder, 'image_url' => $imgUrl);
                    $where = array('option_id =?' => $intOptionId);
                    $adapter->update($optionTable, $data, $where);
                }

                if (in_array($optionId, $object->getDefault())) {
                    if ($object->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') {
                        $attributeDefaultValue[] = $intOptionId;
                    } elseif ($object->getFrontendInput() == 'select') {
                        $attributeDefaultValue = array($intOptionId);
                    }
                }

                // Default value
                if (!isset($values[0])) {
                    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('eav')->__('Default option value is not defined'));
                }

                $adapter->delete($optionValueTable, array('option_id =?' => $intOptionId));
                foreach ($stores as $store) {
                    if (isset($values[$store->getId()])
                        && (!empty($values[$store->getId()])
                        || $values[$store->getId()] == "0")
                    ) {
                        $data = array(
                            'option_id' => $intOptionId,
                            'store_id'  => $store->getId(),
                            'value'     => $values[$store->getId()]
                        );
                        $adapter->insert($optionValueTable, $data);
                    }
                }
            }
            $bind  = array('default_value' => implode(',', $attributeDefaultValue));
            $where = array('attribute_id =?' => $object->getId());
            $adapter->update($this->getMainTable(), $bind, $where);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

My custom field was named **image_url** so I added it to the **$data** variable to be inserted. This will insert values into the column "image_url" of the eav_attribute_option table, but you can manipulate it to store in eav_attribute_option_value in the same method.

4.) For some reason that stack overflow post stated that this **_saveOption** method would be fired on save but mine was not, therefore I also overrode the **_afterSave** method in the same class which looks like this:

```
protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $this->_clearUselessAttributeValues($object);
    $this->_saveStoreLabels($object)
         ->_saveAdditionalAttributeData($object)
         ->saveInSetIncluding($object)
         ->_saveOption($object);

    return $this;
}
```

5.) Now it will attempt to save your new value. But it will cause an error since your custom table column most likely doesn't exist yet. You are welcome to create this manually if it is appropriate for you. Unfortunately I needed to create this programmatically for my situation, so for those of you in the same boat (this is a slightly unclean approach) but for speed I re-routed the **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php** by creating the local revision here: **app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php** and add this to line **154** in the constructor class:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('eav/attribute_option'), 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME_HERE', 'VARCHAR(256) NULL');
$installer->endSetup();
```

6.) Okay, everything should now be saving to the database, but we still need to read the value into our **<td>** - this had me stumped for a while, but figured out that the Javascript is responsible for replacing the {{id}} and {{sort_order}} tags in the HTML on line **230**. Therefore we need to add our new column to this **getOptionsValues()** method. I added the following code in on line **70** of **catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml**:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getOptionValues() as &$val) {
$imgUrl = $this->getImageUrl($val->id);
if ($imgUrl != "0") {
    $val->_data["YOUR_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME_HERE"] = $imgUrl;
}
} ?>
```

Then, in your **YOUR_MODULE_Block_Adminhtml_Options** class add the method **getImageUrl()** that the above calls:

```
/**
* Retrieve results from custom column
*
* @return Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Store_Collection
*/
public function getImageUrl($option_id)
{
    //Get the resource model
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    //Retrieve the read connection
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    //Retrieve our table name
    $table = $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option');
    $query = 'SELECT ' . $this->custom_col . ' FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE option_id = '
    . (int)$option_id . ' LIMIT 1';

    //Execute the query and store the result
    $imgUrl = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);
    return $imgUrl;
}
```

And there you have it. I really hope that this helps anyone in a similar situation.

Comment: Why did you put the extra columns on eav/attribute_option and not eav/attribute_option_value?

Comment: how to apply this to magento 2?

Comment: Maybe try https://store.belvg.com/apply-to-attribute-option.html which could provide a boilerplate but you could adapt it to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

By default Magneto only provide custom options without any description, if you want to customize with description then you must change in following files:

**Step 1:-**

In File

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\option\type\select.phtml
```

Find the below code:

```
'<th class="type-sku"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU') ?></th>'+
```

Add these after just after

```
'<th class="type-description"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Description') ?></th>'+
```

Find the below code:

```
'<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="product[options][{{id}}][values][{{select_id}}][sku]" value="{{sku}}"></td>'+
```

Add these after just after

```
'<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="product[options][{{id}}][values][{{select_id}}][description]" value="{{description}}"></td>'+
```

**Step 2:-**

In File

```
 app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option.php
```

Find the below code:

```
$value['sku'] = $this->htmlEscape($option->getSku());
```

Add these code  just after

```
$value['description'] = $this->htmlEscape($option->getDescription());
```

Find the below code:

```
'sku' => $this->htmlEscape($_value->getSku()),
```

Add these code  just after

```
'description' => $this->htmlEscape($_value->getDescription()),
```

**Step 3:-**

Add field in “catalog_product_option_type_value” table `description`.

Let me know if you have some query.