# Magento setup doesn't save customer attribute option values?

Tags: magento

I'd like to programmatically change the customer address attribute option values so I've created a file and searched around and came to this solution:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'geslacht');
$data['option']['value'] = array(
    8649 => array(
        0 => 'De heer',
        1 => 'heer',
        2 => 'heer'
    ),
    8648 => array(
        0 => 'Mevrouw',
        1 => 'mevrouw',
        2 => 'mevrouw'
    )
);
$data['store_labels'] = array(
    0 => 'Geslacht',
    1 => 'Aanhef',
    2 => 'Aanhef'
);
$attribute->addData($data)->save();
```

And it works perfectly! But... Now I'd like to use this in a setup file for a module I'm creating so I've copied it to a install file and came to this:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'geslacht');
$data['option']['value'] = array(
    8649 => array(
        0 => 'De heer',
        1 => 'heer',
        2 => 'heer'
    ),
    8648 => array(
        0 => 'Mevrouw',
        1 => 'mevrouw',
        2 => 'mevrouw'
    )
);
$data['store_labels'] = array(
    0 => 'Geslacht',
    1 => 'Aanhef',
    2 => 'Aanhef'
);
$attribute->addData($data)->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Now only the store labels are being saved and all option values are cleared! Why can't I use this code in a install file?

Comment: Simple question, if you run again your first script, are the options appearing again ?

Comment: Yes, then they're back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i'm not really sure this will work but it seems to be a possible explaination.
It's possible the problem is caused because when install scripts a run by Magento, the environnement is not fully initialized. The solution can be to move your script into a **data install script**, which will be run after environnement initialization.

The naming conventions for these files are mostly identic to sql scripts but they are located in a separated folder.

This is not the subject here so i'll only post a link about how to create data-install scripts: http://inchoo.net/magento/using-magento-1-6-data-install-scripts/

I have also found a very usefull article: http://vinaikopp.com/2014/11/03/magento-setup-scripts/

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks! I've made a data install script instead of a sql install script and now it's saving all the information!

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the option values to the attribute after it is created. When you call addAttribute initially it will detect the option values array and automatically populate the eav_config_option and eav_config_option_value tables with the necessary info. You can see how the setup script is doing it here (primarily the addAttribute and addAttributeOption functions): http://freegento.com/doc/d0/d7b/_eav_2_model_2_entity_2_setup_8php-source.html

I recently had to do something similar (add a bunch of option values to a custom product attribute) so this might be useful as a guide, it's based on the process in the core file I linked above.

https://github.com/aligent/Aligent_Feeds/blob/47ee0ad0f15a3461d3d228ed663a9e9816d25913/app/code/community/Aligent/Feeds/sql/aligent_feeds_setup/upgrade-0.1.1-0.1.2.php

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a setup function to update attribute option data, named *addAttributeOption*. Its name starts with "add" but it makes update too. There is no setup function to update store labels for an attribute, but luckily your code works for that purpose. So this code may work for your example;

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'geslacht');
$attributeData['store_labels'] = array(
    0 => 'Geslacht',
    1 => 'Aanhef',
    2 => 'Aanhef'
);
$attribute->addData($attributeData)->save();

$optionData['option']['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
$optionData['option']['value'] = array(
    8649 => array(
        0 => 'De heer',
        1 => 'heer',
        2 => 'heer'
    ),
    8648 => array(
        0 => 'Mevrouw',
        1 => 'mevrouw',
        2 => 'mevrouw'
    )
);

$installer->addAttributeOption($optionData); //Function is named "addAttributeOption", but it makes update too.

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save attribute values directly into corresponding database tables:

```
    $installer->run("

    INSERT INTO customer_address_entity_varchar
    (entity_type_id,attribute_id,entity_id,value) 
    VALUES (2,9,1,'Francis');

    ");
```

Dirty, yet very universal and fast.

Comment: You're wrong, those values are stored in the `eav_attribute_option_value` table. In the `customer_address_entity_varchar` table the values from customers are stored, that's not where I'm looking for. And I want to know why my code doesn't work in a setup file, I know I can change it directly into the database.

Comment: Sorry then @Roy. You might look here, under ADDING NEW ATTRIBUTE OPTION heading is a piece of code that might help you. http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/05/addupdate-attribute-option-values.html

Comment: The first part of that page I've used to created my script. The second part is to add a new attribute option, but I want to update them.

Comment: @Roy, have you tried to get the attribute another way? Sometimes it helps `$attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407896/how-to-update-the-attribute-options-programmatically-in-magento

Comment: That one is for catalog attributes, which one should I use for customer address attributes?

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer_address', 'geslacht', array(
'label' => 'De heer',
'type' => 'varchar'
));

$installer->addAttribute('customer_address', 'geslacht', array(
'label' => 'heer',
'type' => 'varchar'
));

// and so on

$installer->endSetup();
```

HTH

Good Luck

Comment: I don't want to create an attribute but change the option values per store of an existing attribute.

Comment: So you want to override existing attribute values, correct? Did you debug your code? Does save() gets called? Otherwise why dont you simply change the values with raw sql? Thats what the installer is made for.

Comment: Yes I want to override the existing values and yes I've debugged some code, `save()` gets called otherwise nothing will be saved (store labels are saved correctly and option values are cleared). I prefer to use the Magento functions instead of working directly in the database. And it is working in a file in the root... So why not in a setup file?